# Special Price From Date and To Date

Tags: price, special-price, magento-1.14

I'd like to directly query `sku`, `special price`, `special price from date`, `special price to date` from database.

We are offering special sale every week with different items. Sale items are supposed to have `from date` and `to date`. Unfortunately many of them are missed `to date`. We haven't cleared old/previous sale information for a long time. So I don't know how many items are on sale now.

Please advise me.

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: It is "Magento ver. 1.14.0.1 Ent."  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You may use following code

```
$collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('price');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date',array(array('from' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate()),
                                 array('special_from_date', 'null'=>true)));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date',array(array('to' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate()),
                                 array('special_to_date', 'null'=>true)));
```

Comment: Thank you, Any chance that I can make the same result by sql query?

Comment: you may get sql query like this
echo $collection->getSelect();

Answer (score 1):

Use below code :

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                                   'sku',
                                   'name'
                   ))
                   ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                   )) 
                   ->addFinalPrice()                       
                   ->getSelect()
                   ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price');
```

with the above collection, you will get list of products which have sale. 
You can also run this code from Magento root testing file so you get idea which products have sale or other information.

For information print, you need to code :

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
[Display Info What You want]
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try now. Do you have any idea that I get get same result by SQL query?

Comment: If you get proper result using above code then you can create SQL query as well.